# UIButton color change

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicolor

I want to change UIButton color from brown color to darkbrown color. How i can do that

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
```

Any ideas that how to change this brown color to darkbrown color.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a darker brown specifically, you can manually specify it:

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:1.0/12 saturation:2.0/3 brightness:4.0/10 alpha:1];
```

(The default brown color has brightness 6.0/10.)

If you want to be able to darken a color in general, you can do it like this:

```
UIColor *color = UIColor.brownColor;
CGFloat hue, saturation, brightness, alpha;
[color getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
brightness *= .8;
UIColor *darkerColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:alpha];
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting on iOS 5 there is a property called tintColor.

> @property(nonatomic,retain)   UIColor     *tintColor

Answer (score 1):

There's no darkBrownColor predefined, but you can create a UIColor with RGB values like so:

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
```